# Encoded form data

Tags: encoding

I process form data emailed as a delimited string. Recently, an additional field is proving perplexing.

I receive the string in base64 coding, which I decrypt before splitting. Viewed from any Windows email utility, the encoded field looks something like this:

```
http://xxx/preloaddocument.aspx?instanceid=1971900&isreadonly=true&internal=false
```

After decrypting and viewing "straight," the field looks something like this:

```
http://xxx/preloaddocument.aspx[?Ý[?ÙZYLNMÌNL   ?\Ü?XYÛ?O]YI?[\??[Y?[ÙOÝ\??
```

The control characters cause it to be seen differently by different viewers.

Regardless of why the query string is formed differently from the rest of the URL, any ideas about how to deal with this? The translated query string should have 50 characters, while the encoded(?) version has 56.

Comment: Solved.
I discovered that my problem was due to a slightly flawed jQuery decoding library. It had worked just fine until the problem described here. That one is called "jquery.crypt".

By changing to a different library (variously distributed, but I'm using as jquery.base64.js), the decoding happens perfectly and the problem described has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is too good a story not to finish.

After discovering jquery.base64.js noted in my comment above, I used it in my SharePoint development site to replace the jquery.crypt.js library that was subtly failing. Worked perfectly, and I then moved the relevant code over to production. Total failure.

Now here's the interesting part. My development site references exactly the same library and files as does production. So, my JavaScript references are identical for both sites. But although that same code worked perfectly in development, over in production the library was evidently found but could not provide any of its methods. I worked on this for a couple hours, and then fell back on the fact that I had replaced one Base64 library with this one--why not try yet another? Not that it made any sense, of course.

So I found webtoolkit.base64.js. That it worked in development meant nothing by this time, but referencing it from the production code also worked, so I can now report true success.